# When I delete from the students table, it will also delete the items on voters table

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am new and don't know how to code well, but I want to modify the system.

TARGET: When I delete the 'id' from the students table it will also delete 'userid' from the voters table.

SCREENSHOT OF DB:

**students TABLE**

[image]

**voters TABLE**

[image]

HERE IS CODE I AM USING. (THIS CODE ONLY DELETE THE ROWS ON students TABLE)
I have tried using another query but nothing happened. Can someone please fix the code for me? I am new to this.

```
<?php ob_start();
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    header("location:../login.php");
}
?>
<?php
include('../connect.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$del = mysqli_query($connection,"DELETE FROM students WHERE id='$id'");

?>
```

Comment: Please provide table structure including all primary keys and foreign keys.

Comment: Why don't you simply run another delete against voters?

Comment: Seems you have join two tables. student table 'id' column with voters table 'userid'.

Comment: Read about `cascade delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a desired functionality when you are using any RDBMS. i.e. when there are 2 tables with a `foreign key relationship` between them and the `foreign key` of the 1st table is a `Primary key` of the 2nd table. Then deleting the 1st tables record will be triggering the `deletion` of the record associated with it in the 2nd table.
This is called a cascade delete which is much better explained with the below definition.
***A foreign key with cascade delete means that if a record in the parent table is deleted, then the corresponding records in the child table will automatically be deleted. This is called a cascade delete in SQL Server.***

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL:**

You can delete with a [`JOIN`](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php) like this:

```
DELETE users
  FROM users
 INNER JOIN voters
         ON users.id = voters.userid
 WHERE users.name = 'Jordan Santos';
```

See [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ce3c6/2) for an example with data. (You can comment out the `DELETE` statement with a `#` to see the query results without deleting anything.)

**Postgres:**
You could use two [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) (i.e., `WITH` clauses) to do the deletions in each table:

```
WITH user_deletion AS (
  -- this deletes the user based on username
  DELETE
    FROM users u
   WHERE username='Dad'
  RETURNING id, username
), 

vote_deletion AS (
   -- this gets the deleted user_id from above and deletes the corresponding vote(s)
   DELETE
    FROM votes
   WHERE user_id = (SELECT id FROM user_deletion)
  RETURNING vote_id, user_id, vote
)

-- this runs the DELETE statements in the clauses above
SELECT udel.*, vdel.* 
  FROM user_deletion udel
 INNER JOIN vote_deletion vdel
    ON udel.id = vdel.user_id;
```

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ccd41/21) for a Postgres example with data, showing results both before and after the deletion.